# Clear Navigationservice Buffer - Or Reset App? (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an app I'm working on where the user gets navigated two pages deep, meaning:

Select stuff, click next -> select stuff, click next -> results

On the results page, I'm doing a Navigationservice.Navigate() back to MainPage.xaml but now the user has the ability to hit the back button which can break some things in the app.  How can I clear that buffer of pages available?  Any way to for Navigationservice.canGoBack return false even if it's true?  If the buffer can't be cleared, the is there a method which will restart the app to get the user back to the MainPage.xaml without having any navigation history?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a few references for solutions to clearing the back stack.

[Want to "reset" an app but how to deal with backstack pages?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/7cbb9e11-3432-4db8-b87d-60d23ade4da9)

[Removing a page from the navigation stack](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/210992dc-04e1-4ae6-b808-13cbf33db318)

[Can the navigation history be cleared](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/226d6ea4-0a69-47fa-bb9c-4d41080e8d97/)

Alternatively, consider Peter Torr's suggestions on handling navigation scenarios.

[Introducing the concept of “Places”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

[Redirecting an initial navigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: This got me going in the right direction.  I set a global boolean variable, goHome, in App.xaml.cs and then evaluated that within OnNavigatedTo() on each page.  Thanks!